# MVC4 Razor - bind object Id from foreach loop to Url.Action that's outside the loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure if this can be done as the `Url.Action()` is trying to access a variable that's only in the foreach's scope - maybe using jQuery?

I have a strongly typed partial view that takes a view model that contains a list of search results.

I iterate through the list and each result is displayed in summarised form. Beside each item in the list there's a button that (*should*) when clicked launches a modal window that displays more detailed information about the list item. So if there's 10 items in the list there's going to be 10 correspdonding 'More info' buttons.

**Partial View:**

```
<div>
@foreach (var result in Model.SearchResults)
{
    <div class="basic-search-result">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <img class="span3" src="http://some-img.jpg" />
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="address">
                    @result.Address.TownCity<br />@result.Address.County
                </div>
                <div>
                    €@result.MonthlyRate Monthly
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3 offset1" id="basic-search-result-btns">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btn-show-modal-from-get-all">More info</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Just below the foreach loop I define the modal (`ViewProperty` is a controller action that returns a partial that contains the modal's body):

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="modal-view-property-from-get-all" 
    data-url="@Url.Action("ViewProperty", "ResidentialProperties", new { id = result.ResidentialPropertyId })">
    <div id="view-property-from-get-all-container"></div>
</div>
```

When one of the buttons is clicked, it should launch a modal. Handled like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-show-modal-from-get-all').click(function () {
        var url = $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').data('url');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#view-property-from-get-all-container').html(data);

            $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

I know that the Id I'm binding in the `Url.Action()` is outside of the scope of the foreach. Is it possible to somehow get the `result.ResidentialPropertyId` and pass it to the `Url.Action()` dynamically when a button is clicked?

To prove it's working, I placed the `Url.Action()` in the foreach loop, but this only launched a modal for the first item in the list. Can what I'm trying to do be achieved?

Comment: when you placed the button inside the foreach loop, was the ids properly getting attached uniquely.

Comment: Are you saying I should put the Url.Action() at each button instead of in the modal definition?

Comment: yup either do that or use custom attributes to attach the ID and than access it in Javascript function.... Let me know if you need any help in writing this code..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not include the `Id` in the `data-url`

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="modal-view-property-from-get-all" 
    data-url="@Url.Action("ViewProperty", "ResidentialProperties")">
    <div id="view-property-from-get-all-container"></div>
</div>
```

With that code the `data-url` will have a value `ResidentialProperties/ViewProperty`.

Then include the `Id` on each row to your button or you can read it from it's container element. I also suggest you remove the id of the button and maybe just have a class to ensure that the ajax call won't get executed for all instances of your buttons

```
// assuming Id is the identifier per row
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block show-modal" 
    data-id="@result.Id">More info</button>
```

and in your js do the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-modal').click(function () {
        var url = $("#modal-view-property-from-get-all").attr('data-url');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#view-property-from-get-all-container').html(data);

            $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does `var id` take value from `data-id="@result.Id`? I've changed it to `data-id="@result.ResidentialPropertyId`. I'm getting a 404 on click - "The controller for path '/undefined/9' was not found or does not implement IController."

Comment: Use `.attr` instead of `.data`.

Comment: Tried that but now error has changed to "The controller for path '/undefined/undefined' was not found or does not implement IController." Changing to `.attr` the url doesn't seem to take the Id. Any other ideas?

Comment: [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuTSw/) that is a representation of my updated answer. You should have something like the html in that fiddle.

Comment: I wasn't changing @Url.Action to ResidentialProperties/ViewProperty. Thanks again for a well explained answer, helps me understand how the url is constructed.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to make things clear and be able to help.